Cardinality of a maximal product-free subset of a group G
I'm trying to understand the paper Product-Free Subsets of Groups by Kiran S. Kedlaya, and I can't understand something that I'm sure is rather basic.
Theorem 3:
In a finite $G$ of order $n$, every maximal product-free subset contains at least $\sqrt{n/3}-1$ elements.
The proof is as follows:
Let $S$ be a maximal product-free subset containing $k$ elements. If $g \not \in S$, then $S \cup \{g\}$ is not product-free, so we can write $g$ as $s_1s_2$, $s_1s_2^{-1}$, or $s_1^{-1}s_2$.
The above makes a lot of sense to me, but the proof follows...
Therefore, $3k^2\geq n-k$
Where did this come from? I get the $n-k$ comes from the fact $g \in G\setminus S$ as $|G\setminus S|=n-k$... I don't know where the $3k^2$ comes from and why it's greater or equal to $n-k$.
Thanks!

There are $k^2$ ways to pick $s_1,s_2,$ and three ways to pick the product one of the options. So you can only exclude at most $3k^2$ elements from adding to $S.$ But for $S$ to be maximal, you have to exclude all $n-k$ elements from being added. So $3k^2\geq n-k.$

It seems like ${1}$ is always a maximal product-free subset, unless product-free is defined differently than I'd expect.
